# Are 'Precise Splash Weapons' 1/Round or 1/Encounter?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, rogue, sneak-attack, archetype

Looking at this...

> **Precise Splash Weapons (Ex):** At 4<sup>th</sup> level, an [underground chemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo-rogue-archetypes/underground-chemist/) can deal [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) damage with [splash weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon). ***The attack must be her first attack that round***, qualify for dealing sneak attack damage (such as against a flat-footed target), and be directed at a creature rather than a square.

Does that mean every round that would be a sneak attack, I could
    keep lobbing a bomb at someone?
 Or is it only the first attack of an encounter?

I am reading a lot of conflicting information on various forums.

Comment: Links to the claims made that are confusing you would improve this question, because then we could address those claims specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If the circumstances that permit the underground chemist to deal sneak attack damage persist, the underground chemist can, on his first attack *each* round, deal sneak attack damage at range with a splash weapon

The alchemist archetype [underground chemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo-rogue-archetypes/underground-chemist/)'s extraordinary ability precise splash weapons *itself* sets the ability's limits, and, while they are legion, the special ability is *not* limited to once per encounter (or less!), but, practically, it may *seem* that way.

I expect the typical reasoning for saying the extraordinary ability precise splash weapons is usable only once per encounter is that it's just *very difficult* to deal sneak attack damage at range A) if the attacker doesn't go before his foe B) on the first round of combat. That is, after the foe's had a chance to take its turn, the foe's no longer flat-footed, and, often, *another* means must be employed to cause the foe to lose its Dexterity bonus to AC so that the underground chemist can deal sneak attack damage at range with a splash weapon on his first attack of the *next* round.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can keep getting the sneak attack damage bonus against the same target round after round.

The only requirement is that it is the underground chemist’s first attack *of that round*. I have no idea where anyone got the idea that it was only once per encounter; the rules are quite clear.

In reality, “per encounter” abilities are very awkward in Pathfinder, because an encounter is not a well-defined thing with a clear ending point, so pretty much nothing in the system is “per encounter.”

Note that it is relatively difficult to achieve the other requirements for sneak attack with a ranged attack, since you cannot flank with a ranged weapon. Furthermore, the damage on sneak attack is quite small unless you are getting it multiple times per round (e.g. Rapid Shot, Two-Weapon Fighting, etc.) which is flat-out impossible with this ability. Just some food for thought in considering the potency of this archetype.

Comment: With [Bomber's Discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/bomber-s-discovery-su/) I could choose [Blinding Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/blinding-bomb-su/). Blind condition denies them dexterity modifier. That's the only real tactic I could think of for repeated, albeit not reliable, use.